# Equivalent norms in $H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a smooth and bounded domain, and define in the space $H=H^2(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ the norm $$\|u\|_H = \|\Delta u\|_2$$ for envery $u\in H.$

My question is, the norm defined above and the norm $$\|u\|_H = \left( \|\Delta u\|^2_2 + \|\nabla u\|^2_2 \right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

are equivalents? How can I show this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these norms are equivalent. One inequality is obvious, so let's prove $\|\nabla u\|_2^2+\|\Delta u\|_2^2\leq C\|\Delta u\|_2^2$. Since $u$ vanishes on the boundary, integration by parts gives
$$
\|\nabla u\|_2^2=\int_\Omega u(-\Delta u)\,dx\leq \frac 1 2\|u\|_2^2+\frac 1 2\|\Delta u\|_2^2.
$$
By the Poincaré inequality, $\|u\|_2\leq C\|\Delta u\|_2$. Thus $\|\nabla u\|_2^2\leq \tilde C\|\Delta u\|_2$.

Comment: In your statment "By the Poincaré inequality..." did you mean $$\|u\|_2 \leq C\|\nabla u\|_2 \leq D \|\Delta u\|_2?$$

In other words, did you use the inequality for $\nabla u$?

Comment: That's just a matter of taste. You can formulate the Poincaré inequality as lower bound on the spectrum of the Dirichlet Laplacian (i.e. $\|u\|_2\leq C\|\nabla u\|_2$) or as a bound on the norm of the inverse of the Laplacian (i.e. $\|u\|_2\leq C\|\Delta u\|_2$). They are both equivalent with algebraically related constants - this is generally true for positive self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING - THIS IS NOT CORRECT**. This answer is not correct, but it does contain some perspective. Following my usual policy, according to which we learn at least as much from mistakes as from correct solutions, I am not deleting it.

This answer contains the first obvious attempt one may perform to solve this problem, and the wall one hits. I am not sure it is really a mistake, but for sure it is a difficulty. MaoWao's answer corrects this approach and produces a right answer.

---

**NOTE**. Here $C$ denotes a generic positive constant whose value may change from line to line.

Apply the inequality of Poincaré to the derivatives $\partial_j u$, you will see that (**The following formula is not properly justified , but I am not really sure it is wrong - see comments**)
$$\lVert \nabla f \rVert_2\le C\lVert D^2 f\rVert_2, $$
where $D^2 f(x)=(\partial_{ij}f)_{i, j =1, 2, 3}$ is the Hessian matrix.  And now it remains to show that
$$
\lVert D^2 f\rVert_2\le C\lVert \Delta f\rVert_2, $$
which is done via integration by parts when $f\in C^\infty$, then extended by density. This last computation is in the book on PDEs of Evans, in the very beginning of the chapter on elliptic regularity.

Comment: Wouldn't you require for $\nabla f$ to vanish on the boundary in order to apply the poincare inequality to the (weak) derivative? $H^1_0$ only guarantees that $f=0$ on the boundary in the trace sense, but not $\nabla f=0$ on the boundary in the trace sense.

Comment: @F.Conrad: You have a point here. However, I am hesitating to require $f\in H^2_0$ for the following reason. If you are right, then the inequality $$\lVert \nabla f\rVert_2\le C \lVert D^2 f\rVert_2$$ must fail. How to prove it fails? The obvious way is to sum a linear term  to $f$, say $g_M(x)=M x_1$, so that the right-hand side is unchanged, while the left-hand side gets bigger. However, if $f\in H^2\cap H^1_0$, nonetheless $f+g_M\notin H^2\cap H^1_0$, because $g_M$ does not vanish on the boundary of $\Omega$. So, the $H^1_0$ requirement suffices to kill the obvious counterexample.

Comment: It is good that MaoWao gave the correct answer. What I write here is true but the proof is not correct, as pointed out by F.Conrad.